# Diffrence between Runnable interface and Thread class realting Callstack

Tags: java

I know the basic difference between `Runnable` interface and `Thread` class in Java.

But, is there difference which is related to Callstack between those two?

Comment: Maybe,he meant `call-stack`!

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the call stack trace is that you see en extra level.

e.g. with plain Thread

```
at somepackage.SomeClass.someMethod
at java.lang.Thread.run
```

if you use a MyRunnableClass you will see

```
at somepackage.SomeClass.someMethod
at mypackage.MyRunnableClass.run
at java.lang.Thread.run
```

Answer (score 0):

Each Java/JVM thread will create a separate call-stack. This is agnostic of whether you use Runnable interface or Thread class.

Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Answer (score -2):

Difference is that if you extend Thread class, you wont be able to extend anything else, but you can pretty much just call the start() method from the class since its inherited. (dont forget to override the run() method).

```
MyThreadClass t = new MyThreadClass();
t.start();
```

Another difference is that if you implement Runnable, you can extend another class if you want, but you need to pass the object as parameter to be able to run it since you only implement the run() method.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunnableClass());
t.start();
```

Besides from that, there isnt any difference on how they are executed.

edit: dont really understand what you mean by "callstrack".